# Writing jukugo where only some kanji are known

Tags: kanji, orthography, kana, handwriting

Having studied Japanese for two years so far, there are many instances of vocabulary that I have learned but for which I know [the 書き方 of] only some of the kanji that make up the word. Is there any convention for writing parts of a word, that would normally be written in kanji if known, in kana (either 片仮名 or 平仮名)?

To provide an example, for the word 「濁{だく}点{てん}」, the second character 「点」is learned much earlier than the first character 「濁」. If I were to try to write this on paper (as opposed to on a computer, where kana->kanji conversion is mostly automatic), my instinct is to write the kanji that I know and leave the rest in hiragana, rendering this word 「だく点」. Of course, depending on situation there is the option of looking in a dictionary, but even then  for some kanji the 書き方 is hard to intuit (such as in the case of kanji like 「鬱」where some of the radicals are uncommon in low-mid level kanji, have high stroke counts, or are otherwise difficult to write from first principles).

Answer (score 0):

## 日本語

この日本語での回答は、私の英語力不足のために多々誤訳があり、英訳でこの回答を読む人に私の回答の趣旨が正しく伝わらないことを懸念して、回答内容に疑義が生じた場合に、本来の回答の趣旨を確認していただくためのものです。

質問者の質問を正確に理解しているか確認するために、以下に質問の日本語訳を載せます。

> これまで２年間日本語を勉強してきて、かなりの語彙が増えてきました。しかし、全部を漢字で書けるかとなると話は違います。一つの単語でも漢字で書けるところとそうでないところがあります。そこで質問ですが、**本当なら漢字で書くべき部分**を平仮名とか片仮名とかで書くというようなことは日本でも行われていますか。
>
> 「濁点」という単語を例に挙げると、２番目の「点」は、「濁」よりもずっと早く覚えられます。仮名漢字変換がほとんど自動的に行われるコンピュータではなく、これを手書きしようとすると、私が漢字を知っている部分だけを漢字で書き、残りを平仮名にすると、「だく点」のようになります。もちろん、状況によっては辞書を見るということもできますが、それでも漢字によっては見ただけで書き方が難しいと直感でわかる場合もあります（「鬱」のような漢字の場合、初中級レベルの漢字にはない部首もあり、画数も多く、どこから書き始めるかも困難です）。

次の部分は英訳にはありませんが、私が回答をする上で大切だと考えた部分です。

「書き物」は目に見える文字列を通じて他人に自分の意図をきちんと伝える道具としての役割があります。そこでは、抑揚や間（ま）が使える話し言葉と違う配慮が必要かと思います。私が使った「きちんと伝える」とは、誤解なく伝えるという意味はもちろんですが、読む人の読み易さも含んでいます。英語と違って単語と単語の間にスペースを置かない日本語では、幸い、ひらがな、カタカナ、漢字等の複数種類の文字を適宜使えますので、これらの字種を必要に応じて切り替えることは読み易さを向上さす上で欠かせません。特に漢字の場合には、他の字種と違って表意文字としての機能もありますので、その働きは書き物として大変大きいものがあるように思います。今回の質問者の趣旨を客観的に見ますと、本来漢字で表すべきところの一部を仮名で代用できるかというものです。質問者が日本人でないことを考慮しての回答もありますが、**日本人からの質問に対する回答としても問題ない内容であるべきだ**と判断し回答することにしました。

narutoさんが質問者へのコメント欄で紹介した記事の内容を見ました。

大変良く書かれておりますが、結果としてどの表現が許容されるかの判断が曖昧です。また、例えば辞書を引くことができないようなとき、どのように対処するのが次善の策になるのかというような具体的方法の提示がありません。それは本来漢字で書くべきところの一部を仮名で代替することが、本来その漢字が果たしていたどの機能を失うことになるのか視点が薄弱だからと判断しました。

「み力的」と「魅りょく的」の例がありますが、「その衣装は魅力的」という文章で置き換えてみるとすぐにわかります。「その衣装はみ力的」「その衣装は魅りょく的」。字種の切り替えの位置の大切さがどれだけ読み易さに貢献しているか、また、「魅りょく的」はあっても「み力的」はないことも分かります。拠（よんどころ）無い事情があって、どうしても「魅」の字を書けず恥を忍んで、「その衣装は『み力的』」とすれば、何故『み力的』と書くのかと怪訝（けげん）に思われますが、意図した意味は伝わり、その場は何とか凌（しの）げるような気もします。

ここで、本来の回答に戻ります。

確かに、[ここ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19491/can-i-insert-hiragana-in-words-i-only-know-partially-how-to-write)には、漢字ですべてを書くことなく部分的にひらがなを書くことができる例があります。 しかし、その単語や熟語のすべてを漢字で書くより、部分的にひらがなを用いることが一般的に受け入れられている場合にのみの説明として理解する必要があります。

あなたが一部の漢字を知らないあるいは思い出せない場合は、辞書やインターネット上で調べて、すべて漢字で書くことが普通です。 たとえあなたが日本人でないことを承知している相手に何かを書く場合であっても、あなたが知っているところだけを漢字で書き、残りの部分を仮名で書くことは、十分な対処方法だとは思われせんので、私は勧めません。
しかし、自分だけのメモのように他人に見せる必要がない場合は、いちいち辞書を調べず、漢字がわからないところはひらがなで書くということは我々でも普通にしています。

憂鬱の鬱ような極端な例を根拠に、あなたが本来するべき対処方法を見失わないでいただきたいと思います。
憂鬱の場合は、カギ括弧「」を使って「ゆううつ」あるいは「憂うつ」と、また濁点の場合は「だく点」と書き表すことで何らかの理由があってそうしていることを伝えることができるように思います。

あなたの質問とは離れますが、普通の日本人でも、コンピュータでのかな漢字変換を使わなければ、憂鬱という漢字を手書きで書くことはできません。コンピュータを使用する場合での話ですが、たとえばある単語はひらがなで書くことが普通であっても、英語とは異なり、日本語には単語と単語の間にスペースがないために、その単語をひらがなで書いてしまうと、前後に存在するひらがなと区別することは難しくなることがあります。このため、その単語を敢えて難しい漢字で書くことがあります。この場合、あなたの質問とは逆の条件になりますが、憂鬱（ゆううつ）のようにカッコでふりがなを書いて、あなたが書いた難しい漢字を読む人に読む上で困らないような配慮が必要です。今後あなたが努力をすることで、「憂鬱」を簡単に書けるようになるときが来ると思います。そのとき、このような配慮をしていただければと思います。

## English

Certainly, there are examples [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19491/can-i-insert-hiragana-in-words-i-only-know-partially-how-to-write) that you can write partially in *hiragana* without writing all in *kanji*.
However, you need to know that it is accepted only when writing *hiragana* in part is more popular or commonly accepted than writing all in *Kanji* for the word or the *jukugo*.

If you do not know or remember the partial *kanji*, it is common for Japanese to look it up in a dictionary or on the Internet and write it all in *kanji*s. Although it may be accepted even if you write the *jukugo* partially in *kanji*s and the rest in *kana*s to a person who knows that you are not a Japanese, it seems an inadequate solution and I'll not recommend it.

However, if you need not to show to other people such as a memorandum of understanding, we usually write in *hiragana* instead of unknown *kanji* without examining the dictionary.

Do not lose what you should do by an extreme exception such as 鬱 in 憂鬱.
In the case of 憂鬱, I think that you can write it 「ゆううつ」or 「憂うつ」and 「だく点」for 濁点 by using *kagi* brackets 「」to tell you know the expression having some reason.

Apart from your question, even ordinary Japanese people can not write 憂鬱 in kanji by handwriting except writing using kana-kanji conversion on computers.
In the case of using a computer, even if writing in hiragana is ordinary for  a certain word, unlike English, Japanese has no space for each word, so it is hard to be distinguished from hiragana existing before and after if the word is written in hiragana. Because for this reason, it is sometimes happen to write it in difficult kanji intentionally. In this case, it is a condition opposite to your question, but it is kind to write furigana with  parentheses like 憂鬱（ゆううつ）so that people who read the difficult word you wrote will not cause hardship in reading it. This kind consideration is desirable in the future when you can easily write 憂鬱 after your hard efforts and practice.

Comment: 漢字かな交じりになって読み辛くなったらカギ括弧で囲めというのは具体的な対処法の提案としてはずいぶん奇妙なものに思えます。少なくとも学校ではそんな指導はされないですよね。いっそ全部ひらがなにしたほうがまし（これは向こうの回答にも書かれている具体的対処法）とか、カタカナを使え、とかいうなら理解できますが。

Comment: @naruto: 必要な漢字を表記できていないということだけは分かっているが、どの表記が読み手に取って読み辛いのかどうかが判断できない人にとって、保険の効いた策はどのようなものがあるかを考えますと、正解は自ずと分かると思います。むろん「」でなくとも、前後に若干スペースを空けるだけでも読み手にはありがたいかと思います。むろんカタカナでも良いでしょう。質問者の立場を考え、また、枝葉をつつかず大きな幹を見てご判断ください。「向こうの回答」とは具体的に何をさすか示されていないので判断できませんが、全部ひらがないにした方がましという読み手のことを考えない案はいずれ改良されることを願っております。

Comment: 向こうの回答というのはsnailplaneさんのものです。全部ひらがなというのは「出たら目」「み力的」「立ぱ」の代わりに「でたらめ」「デタラメ」「みりょく的」「りっぱ」にした方がむしろ好ましい、という話です。個人的には納得できますし、小学校の国語の教科書は大抵そのようになっています。「読みやすさを考慮し、恥を偲んでカギ括弧で囲んで凌ごう」というのよりは一般的・具体的・現実的なアドバイスではないでしょうか。

Comment: @naruto: 不明な点は了解しました。その上で、カギ括弧（これに限らず若干のスペースでもその他の区別できる記号でも良いのですが）はあなたからのコメントでも有効に作用しており、読み手である私にはありがたい存在だと思います。次に、まだ全部は書けないが部分的にでも覚えた漢字を使ってみたいと思っているであろうこのたびの質問者の心理を考えますと、小学生が漢字を少しずつ学習することと背景事情が違いますので、全部覚えるまではそれでも全部ひらがなで書きなさいとは私には言いにくいのですが...。それよりも、そんなややこしい議論をする前に、幹を見てほしいといったのは、「基本として辞書で調べなさい。私どももそうしております。」と私は書きました。これが伝わるのが回答の本筋です。日本人回答者と思われる人たちが枝葉末節なことを議論しているのを質問者が見たらどう思いますか。どう対処したらよいか迷うのは必然です。このサイトの本筋は常に質問者第一ではないでしょうか。枝葉末節な議論を持ち出すぐらいなら、例えば私の回答を引用しながらご自身の案を堂々と展開して回答として提出するのが良いと思います。