# What is this 連用形+ゆる grammar? How is it different from the potential form?

Tags: grammar, classical-japanese, potential-form

I have come across this grammar a lot lately:

> 連用形+ゆる

For example, in [this comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13938/why-did-asahi-shinbun-write-%E5%AD%90%E3%81%93%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82-instead-of-%E5%AD%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A9%E3%82%82-in-this-headline#comment30088_13940),

> 文語と現代語を交じたる文はインターネットで**見ゆる**なあ

I've also heard しゆる. Judging from the context I think that this grammar is similar to the potential form. So 見ゆる is basically 見える and しゆる is できる.

Am I right? How do the two grammars differ?

Comment: Is it perhaps dialect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

見ゆ is an archaic ヤ行 verb meaning 見える in modern Japanese. 見ゆる is the attributive form (連体形) of 見ゆ.

- [古文単語「みゆ/見ゆ」の意味・解説【ヤ行下二段活用】](http://manapedia.jp/text/4191)

In modern Japanese, there is no verb that ends with ゆ, but in archaic Japanese some verbs ended with ゆ.

- [燃ゆ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E7%87%83%E3%82%86) (=燃える in modern Japanese)
- [覚ゆ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A6%9A%E3%82%86) (=覚える in modern Japanese)

Etymologically, yes, ゆ was an archaic auxiliary verb which was used similarly to れる/られる. See [ゆ (as a 助動詞)](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%86) in a 古語辞典.

見ゆ is still occasionally used in titles and such ([example](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00Y9J5OCW)), but 見ゆるなあ sounds to me like a strange mixture of modern and archaic Japanese.

Comment: Ah ha.  So this is not dialect!  Nevertheless, I was wondering whether it might be related to える as in みることをえない.  Any thoughts on that?  (I mean in addition to what you already wrote).

Comment: @A.Ellett Perhaps they are related, but I don't now how. Nevertheless, I somehow felt しゆる should mean the same thing as しうる.

Comment: 得{え}る vs 得{う}る.  I always get confused by those two.  :-)

Comment: Kana does not have a means to write /ye/, but the relationship is much clearer in romanization. 見ゆる miyuru -> 見える miyeru. As there is no /ye/, the initial /y/ drops out leaving only /e/. The change from /-u-/ to /-e-/ is regular and found in all 下二段 verbs that simplified to 下一段.